# HTML/CSS (slash JS?) 3-column layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

Imagine I wanted to have a *single* `<span>` with stuff inside that has its text/contents split into three columns of as equal height as possible.  How can this be done?

Comment: if you are ok with splitting the columns into 3 divs just use CSS tables. Create a container div for the columns and set it to 'display:table'. Then on the child divs set them to width:33.3% and 'display:table-cell'. I if you want automatic 3 column flow layout in one element you'll need some heavy javascript. CSS is supposed to support in the future but not any time soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's the [CSS3 column layout](http://caniuse.com/#search=column%20lay). currently, it's supported via vendor tags. a sample can be seen in [this article](http://www.webkit.org/blog/88/css3-multi-column-support/) of webkit's site where there is a 2-celled div created from a single div only.

Comment: Is there a solution that works cross-browser? (AKA with IE? :P) Like a JQuery plugin or something?

Comment: i don't know of any. given your single span issue, you can use this as of today if you don't mind supporting <IE9 and < Opera 11.

Comment: @TND you should put that as an answer :D

Comment: ...odd.  Stack Overflow gives me a JavaScript error every time I try to click on "Answer Your Question"...  I'm using the latest Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Matthew James has a [very nice article](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks) about flexible, multiple-column layouts that work even in older browsers.

**Edit:** Just tested it in IE6 quirks mode and it still looks beautiful!

Answer (score 0):

May be this?

```
span {
  columns: auto 3;
  -moz-column-rule: auto 3;
  -webkit-column-rule: auto 3;
  max-height: 100px;
}
```